# Однотипные блоки php

Tags: php

Небольшой сайт 5 страниц. Футер хедер одинаковые

прописываю их так На каждой странице:

```
<? 
include 'blocks/header.php'; 
?>

<!-- Здесь код страницы -->

<? 
include 'blocks/footer.php'; 
?>
```

Внешне всё отображается как нужно.

верно ли я делаю или более хороший способ есть?

каждая страница на сайте имеет расширение php, нормально ли это? (просто сам неоч разбираюсь)

Comment: очень смутно проглядывается вопрос, расподробьтесь немного, пор фавор.

Comment: Не нормально, для генерации html-страниц следует использовать нормальные шаблонизаторы, а это их жалкое подобие

Comment: @andreymal Спорный вопрос. PHP и так по сути - шаблонизатор. (Хотя я тоже за использование шаблонизаторов - удобнее они все-таки). Подобный подход используется даже в немаленьких проектах и в очень популярных CMS. Шаблонизаторы же все-таки кушают дополнительное время процессора и память

Comment: @tutankhamun ну в нормальных шаблонизаторах вставка хедеров и футеров делается каким-нибудь `{% extends 'base.html' %}`. Не знаю, может ли так чистый php, но вариант, указанный в тексте вопроса, я считаю никуда не годящимся

Comment: У меня только два замечания: 1. Не используйте короткие теги `<?`; 2. Подобные страницы не должны содержать обработку данных, а должны вызываться из страниц, которые ее осуществляют (читайте про разделение логики и отображения)

Answer (score 1):

Если для сайта 5 страниц и он никогда больше не будет расти, то нормально. В большинстве книг по PHP так описано создание сайта. 
Лет 5-7 назад много кто так делал. 
Сейчас конечно принято использовать использовать паттерн [MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller), но это уже другая история.